# Ordinary differential equations and homogeneous substitution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve following differential equation:
$$2xy' + y = y^2 \sqrt{x-x^2y^2} $$

My attempt was to write equation in form $y' = f(\frac{y}{x})$,   but that didn't help  me.I tried substitution :

$$z(x)=xy(x)$$ that gives:
$$z' = (\frac{z}{x})^2\sqrt{x-z^2} + \frac{z}{x}$$

Comment: Better try $z(x)=\sqrt{x}y(x)$, this should absorb and simplify more terms.

Comment: @Dr.LutzLehmann $z=y^2x$ works too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making the change of variable

$$
y = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x z(x)}}
$$

we obtain

$$
x z'\sqrt{z}+z\sqrt{1-\frac 1z}=0
$$

which is separable, giving

$$
z = \frac 14\left((\ln x-C_1)^2+4\right)
$$